# inverting op-amp configuration using lm324n ic

Tags: operational-amplifier

How can I create an inverting amplifier configuration with a gain of 10 in lm324n op-amp integrated circuit. As lm324n has only 1 supply voltage and ground how can I get a negative voltage at the output. I tried this with non-inverting and it is working fine but the problem is with inverting configuration.

Comment: There are many example circuits of opamp based amplifiers to be found if you google for "opamp schematic", select to search for images (pictures) instead of just the web. Have a look at some examples and see how it's done.

Comment: To get a negative output you need a negative supply. The LM324 works fine with +V and -V supplies, not just with +V and Gnd.

Comment: Google "single supply opamp". Lots of results with the basics.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly the LM324 is quite happy on either single or dual supply configurations.

Secondly you can put a voltage other than ground on the non-inverting input. The amplifier will then operate relative to this voltage. So for example if you build an inverting amplifier with a gain of -10 and a voltage of 2.5V on the non-inverting input then connect 2.6V to the inverting input of your circuit you will get 1.5V on the output.

Comment: will it be fine even if I don't include a voltage on the non-inverting side?

Answer (score 0):

LM324 has no problem operating with dual supplies. On page 1 of the datasheet you'll see:

[image]

Comment: How can I build a integrator circuit using op-amp when I give a dc supply across the input as after the capacitor gets charged then the flow of current will stop?